# How to prevent Android take screenshot even when I launch another app activity

Tags: android, security

My App has a security issue, and we hope other people could not see the screenshot by recent apps list. And it's easy to set `LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE` to Window. But if I launch any other app activity, it fails. Does anyone have any ideas on  how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that might help you, have you tried hiding your important view in case of `onPause()` or at least changing its content

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot prevent the ActivityManager from taking screenshot of other Activities which has no Window flags set to WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE.

if your App is concerned with security, you can apply this Flag to all the activity's window for which you don't want to show screenshot in recents.